# Loading text in QTextEdit from down up like in Terminal

Tags: python, qt, terminal, pyqt, pyqt4

I am willing to make a Terminal like QTextEdit using pyqt4, but do not know what property to edit,so that when text from a process is dumped, it should start from the bottom and goes up.

Any help for a starting point would be really appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I tried similar things before. For logging. Its a pain and it is very slow for a lot of lines.

If you expect having a lot of lines cummulating in the terminal then consider writing an item model and attach it to a view.

There are lot of possibilites in tweaking the appearance of such a view and it allows showing a small portion out of a big amount of data without becoming painfully slow. Also it allows to insert data at any position quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to basically reset the cursor of the `QTextEdit` every time you print any text in it.

Let's say you have a QTextEdit class member called resultbox. Then this is what you would want to do -

```
def move_cursor_to_end(self):
    cursor = self.resultbox.textCursor()
    cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
    self.resultbox.setTextCursor(cursor)
```

Calling this function will allow you to move the text cursor to the end of the `QTextEdit` so that when you print anything to it the next time, it will be printed at the end of it.

So basically, while printing to the `QTextEdit`, you can do something like this -

```
def print_to_textedit(self, text):
    self.resultbox.insertPlainText(text)
    self.move_cursor_to_end()
```

This will allow the text to start at the bottom and move up as more text comes along.

Hope this is what you are looking for.